# HTML Grid Layout Template area 2/3

Tags: html, grid

How can I design a layout that 1st row is 1/3 and 2nd row is 2/3 of height? I tried with using template area:

```
 'header header header header header header'
    'menu menu main main right right'
    'menu menu main main right right';
```

but the rows are of same height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu menu main main right right'
    'menu menu main main right right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is enough just to specify the number of fractions for each row - `grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr`:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'header header header'
  'menu main right';
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'header header header'
  'menu main right';
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
</div>
```